# I can't install OIsurv package in R, what can i do?

Tags: r

I can't install OIsurv package in R.
ı am trying to install but I'm getting the following warning:

```
install.packages("OIsurv")

Warning in install.packages :
unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Cgdm/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘OIsurv’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
Warning in install.packages :
unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0:
cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/PACKAGES'
```

What can i do?

Comment: Meanwhile, I install the latest versio of R

Answer (score 1):

The [repository website](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/OIsurv/index.html) says that the package has been removed from CRAN.

You can still compile the package from source but may run into problems. At that point I would try downgrading the R version or perhaps exploring what the problem is and change the source code.

Comment: Which old version should I use? How will I understand this?

Comment: Usually this kind of information is in the `DESCRIPTION` file of the source code. Try installing it with your current R version first, though.